How to calculate large matrix exponentiation

Let $L$ be a linear mapping on functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$(Lf)(x,y) := f(0,0)(1-x^2-y^2) + f(1,0)x^2 + f(0,1)y^2$$
The range of $L$ is contained within the vector space spanned by a basis $B:= \{1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2\}$. Let $A$ be the matrix representation of the function $T:B \to B$ such that $T(f)=Lf$, with respect to the basis $B$. Find $A^{2022}$.

I have found $A$ as the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I know that a large arbitrary number such as 2022 must mean that there is some intuition about the nature of the matrix that can be used as opposed to just multiplying the matrix with itself two thousand times. I don't seem to have the insight to solve this, how might this be approached?

One thing to note is, that $A$ is a block-diagonal matrix, so you can simply compute the powers of individual blocks. Together with @kirafa 's hint, you should arrive at an answer pretty quickly.

Why do you even put the functions (of $(x,y)$) denoted $x$, $y$ and $xy$ in your spanning set of the image? They are clearly not needed, as the definition constructs a linear combination of the constant function$~1$, $x^2$, and $y^2$.

It seems that $A^2 = A$.

You're right - there is a trick. For a problem like this, sometimes it's helpful to try multiplying the matrix to itself once, or maybe twice, and trying to see if there's a pattern. Try comparing $A$ to $A^2$. From there you might be able to immediately deduce what $A^{2022}$ should be.

In this case, as Kirafa pointed out, it is very easy to guess what $A^{2022}$ is just by taking a look at $A^2$. In general, you may want to diagonalize the matrix, that is, writing it as $ A = S \Lambda S^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$ and the columns of $S$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. With this decomposition, you can easily see that $A^2 =  (S \Lambda S^{-1})( S \Lambda S^{-1}) = S \Lambda^2S^{-1}$ and, more generally, $A^n = S \Lambda^n S^{-1}$.

Remark: Even without clever tricks like finding patterns or applying decompositions, $A^n$ can be achieved in $O(\log_2 n)$ through repeated squaring. In binary, 2022 = 11111100110₂, therefore.
$$A^{2022} = A^{1024}⋅A^{512}⋅A^{256}⋅A^{128}⋅A^{64}⋅A^{32}⋅A^{4}⋅A^{2}$$
Since the powers of 2 can be calculated via $A^{2^k} = (A^{2^{k-1}})^2$, this approach takes 17 matrix multiplications as opposed to thousands.
